PWA Studio Store URLs 301 redirect problem of trailing "/" and uppercase letters
Describe the bug
Normally Magento2 with Luma; at backend manage the redirects of certain SEO needs, for example:
At Luma any URL trailing with "/" automatically redirects to original URL w/o "/"
At Luma if you change any letter at URL with the UPPERCASE one again Luma redirects automatically to lowercase original store URL (category, product or CMS pages)
At Luma also www and non www redirects are working w/o problem, for example if your Base_url is https://www.domain com and you write https://domain.com at browser; Magento URL resolver redirects the URL automatically to https://www.domain.com
Those above 3 default Magento behaviour is not working on Venia storefront; https://venia.magento.com
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
Go to https://venia.magento.com/venia-bottoms.html?page=1
at Browser manually change the URL https://venia.magento.com/venia-bottoms.html/?page=1 (added "/" end of url)
Or at Browser manually change the URL https://venia.magento.com/venia-**BO**ttoms.html?page=1 (added "/" end of url)
Expected behavior
Expected behaviour Venia should replace the url with original URL like this:
https://venia.magento.com/venia-bottoms.html?page=1
Also at console we need to see 301 redirect at headers.
But Venia is not making 301 redirect and show the page URL like we have changed:
https://venia.magento.com/venia-bottoms.html**/**?page=1 OR
https://venia.magento.com/venia-**BO**ttoms.html?page=1
So, Google indexes two or more pages for each store page; what is not correct. It is a big fault for SEO...
Venia is not using backend URL resolvers OK.
BUT also does not have built in functionality for 301 redirections.
Same case Admin/Marketing/URL Rewrites.
Now at Venia Storefront 301 URL redirects working but showing 200 at headers but needs to show 301 at headers
I didn't find any solution for those 301 redirect cases for Venia...
